# Where is the difference between those 2 convolutional layers in keras?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I was following 2 different tutorials about basic CNNs and keras (Tensorflow backend) Conv2D layers.

When i swap one layer with an (in my opinion) identical one, with a different notation my model completely fails and goes from ~95% accuracy to under 20%.

Obviously there must be a major difference that i did not spot!

This is my working model, that works as expected:

```
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))

    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu'))

    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

If i replace the second layer

```
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu'))
```

with

```
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
```

I've read that the kernel size can also be defined like (3, 3) this in a tupel and that the default stride size is 1x1.

Why would this replacement result in any different result at all ?

Comment: Which backend are you using?

Comment: Tf, edited my post

Comment: I just tested this on MNIST (I guess you too?). For me the performance is identical as expected. Keras version: 2.2.2, TF version: 1.9.0

Comment: Yeah exactly but i am not changing anything besides this one line.

But then i can atleast assume that it's normally working...

Thank you!

Comment: Both `kernel_size` and `strides` can be  an integer or tuple/list of 2 integers. If they are an integer, they will specify the same value for all spatial dimensions. Basically, these two lines give the same results. There must be something wrong you are doing. https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/